# AttributeError in accessing column in a dataframe to verify dtype through a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dtype

I am trying to replace nan s in the dataframe thus I need to access float or integers column:
it works without using the for loop

```
for col in df:
    if(df.col.dtype!="object"):
        aux=df[col].mean() 
        df[col].fillna(aux,inplace=True)
```

The error I get:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The dot notation in pandas is a shortcut and will not work in this situation.  You are best using df[col].dtype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is `df[col].dtype`